# Markup to play flash video with sound muted?

Tags: html, flash

Is there a way to play a flash video with sound muted in a similar way to HTML5's  attribute 'muted'?

Something like  would be ideal but I don't see it in the spec here:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

So perhaps a FlashVars value or similar?

Comment: I just noticed stackoverflow removed my example markup (newbie!).  2nd paragraph should read 'Something like &lt;param name=\"muted\" value=\"false\"&gt; would be ideal...

Answer (score 0):

What player were you looking to use?

http://flowplayer.org/docs/ has a muted option.

Comment: Thanks Mark, however I wasn't actually thinking along the lines of a specific player.  I was just considering the markup within the 'fallback' <object> tags, as opposed to the the HTML5 part.